# how to run libGDX html project

Tags: libgdx

[image]

How can I run html project in libgdx?
I am using libgdx with android studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can click on "html", or go to http://localhost:8080/html

Comment: Yes, I got it now?  Thank you very much @John